# Easy way to do and undo CSS transition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, transition

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this than what I'm thinking.

My code is simple:

```
   document.body.style['-webkit-transition'] = "background 2s";
        document.body.onmouseover = function(){
            this.style.background = "#000";
        }
```

I'm wanting to implement this into a test library, but I need to know if there is a simpler way of undoing the transition once the user mouses out of the document body.

When I say simpler, I mean I don't want to have to write out "document.body.onmouseout='...'".
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you serious? Just write the mouseout.

Comment: Yeah, I'm serioius. I don't want to write the mouseout because I want to be able to set up transitions for EACH kind of event, (oninput, onmouseover, onclick, onmousedown, onmouseup). What I'm wanting is a general code that undoes the transition for ALL of these events.

Comment: What would be the event for undoing the onclick event?

Comment: I don't know exactly. What I'm wanting to know is how to 1. Apply a transition. 2. Change the styles to execute the transition. and 3. Reset the original style once the transition has been executed and the element loses hover/focus or whatever.

Comment: You can create an array of opposites for every type of event. onmousedown - onmouseup, onkeydown - onkeyup, etc. Then for each of the given events all it would require something along these lines: `document.body[event] = function(){ this.data = {background: this.style.background}; this.style.background = "#000"} document.body[opposite] = function() {this.style.background = this.data.background}`.

Comment: The only general advice I can give is that you should define all your CSS in classes and then add/remove the classes in JS. That said, you gotta handle the events you want to handle. There are no shortcuts. This is a serious _how can I do programming without any programming_ type question.

Comment: I'm not using CSS classes? I want transitions on the fly with JavaScript, with no pre-defined CSS rules. Basically to "program" transitions with JavaScript.

Comment: That is a terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks, Mathletics. That was good advice.

Comment: My goal is to utilize native CSS3 through JavaScript, not use a bulky library like jQuery that uses nothing BUT JavaScript. jQuery animations are pointless.

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery? You should do native CSS animations _through CSS_ is my point.

Comment: I think what Mathletics is trying to say (and what was knocking in my brain) - `document.body[event] = function(){ this.setAttribute('class', this.getAttribute('class')+' transition-'+event)} document.body[opposite] = function(){ this.setAttribute('class', this.getAttribute('class').replace('transition-'+event, '')); }` and put all transitions in CSS triggered by the addition of the class. If that makes sense.

Comment: Mathletics - Yeah, but CSS doesn't let me define callback functions, functions at the start of an animation/transition, or write expressions for values. CSS is good for pre-defined and INITIAL styles. What I want is on the fly, and more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the mouseout, as Mathletics suggests.  The only way to know if Elvis has left the building is to write the "Elvis left the building" handler.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is this. In your CSS, define some transitions.

```
* {
    -webkit-transition: background 2s linear;
}

.fade-to-black {
    background: #000;
}
```

Then your script simply adds and removes this class, simplifying your handlers. You could even write a wrapper to generate the proper handlers. There is definitely room for improvement here, but this is a quick and dirty example to get you going.

```
function handleTransition(direction, type) {
    var handler;
    if (direction) {
       handler = function() {
        this.className += type;
       }
    } else {
        handler = function() {
            this.className = this.className.replace(type, '');
        }
    }
    return handler;
}

document.getElementById('someElement').onmouseover = handleTransition(1, 'fade-to-black');

document.getElementById('someElement').onmouseout = handleTransition(0, 'fade-to-black');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jgdj7/1/)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a solution myself.
Sort of what @eithedog was saying, toggling between "on" and "off" with opposites. Also by setting a transition that takes the same amount of time it takes when "on" as "off". 
A transition onclick doesn't make that much sense, that's basically an animation. Other than that, everything is sorted out.